# Visual Studio загружает старые версии файлов программы

Tags: visual-studio-2019, облако

Непервый раз сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой:

Пишется приложение. Все файлы приложения синхронизируются с облаком Mega.nz. ПК практически никогда не выключаю, тупо блокирую свою учетную запись Windows.

Теперь ситуация:
На следующий день запускаю Visual Studio, а у меня запускается не последняя версия проекта, а какая-то более ранняя (возможно та, которая делалась пару дней назад), но при этом, каждый раз, при уходе с работы я сохраняю и компилирую проект.

P.S. Файлы в папке Debug - последней версии, т.е. открывается приложение(.exe), последнее изменённое.

Есть подозрение, что это облако заменяет каким-то образом новые файлы на старые, но почему тогда оно не трогало файлы из папки Debug?..

Comment: После компиляции и завершения работы с проектом вы его сразу сохраняет в облако?

Comment: @Алексей Бобрович, cтоит синхронизация папки с проектами и облаком в режиме онлайн. Но уже вроде как разобрался, всё-таки проблема с облаком